# Mongoose - how to expire/delete a subdocument?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to expire a subdocument after 30 seconds. Anything I tried so far doesnt do anything.

What I tried:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String
    },
    reports: [ReportSchema]
})

mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

const reportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    createdAt: { 
        type: Date,
        expires: 30
    },
});
```

also tried:

```
const reportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    createdAt: { type: Date,  expires: 30 }
});
```

also tried:

```
reportSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTL index is an index. Expiration time applies to the whole document in reportSchema collection but it won't update any related documents.

You need to keep reportSchema on separate collection to benefit from the TTL index, use references in productSchema instead of embedding them.
Please read about referencing in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

As a side note, the eraser kicks in every minute, so you may still see documents remain in the collection after 30 sec.

**UPDATE**

There is no built-in functionality to remove subdocuments. You need to implement own "expirator" - a cron job, a daemon, or any other mean to periodically run something like this query:

```
db.products.update({
  "reports.createdAt": {
    $lte: new Date()
  }
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "reports": {
      "createdAt": {
        $lte: new Date()
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand. so my reports subdocument, is always an array of reports (objects). Are you saying that specifying expiration date, would only delete ALL the reports/the whole array but cannot expire single reports?!

Comment: ok, I tried to update the answer but I can't really put it simpler. Indexes apply on collection level. Embedded documents has no collection on its own - they are embedded into parent documents. On the database level there is no difference between embedded schemas and nested paths.  It should be obvious if you look into the db without mongoose, like manually with mongosh/compas/robomongo

Comment: thank you, I understand. Is there any way I could expire embedded documents? In my case using references instead wouldnt be beneficial and I would only do it so they can expire

Comment: thank you for the update. Can I just ask, what is performance wise better: having references (therefore 2 lookups instead of 1 when its embedded) if its not really needed (my reports are currently embedded because there will never be too many so size shouldnt be an issue) or keeping reports embedded but having a cron job to periodically remove certain reports?

Comment: You need to test performance, there are too many factors to consider - data size, capacity, indices, query patterns etc. As a rule of thumb, lookups are more expensive.